# Use report of cucumber in Karate

Tags: automation, cucumber, karate

Hello i new in karate framewrok, i need help to integrate the graphics report of cucumber in karate, i view a function in a video or a post but the people dont tell how libraries import tu use the same.

The function that i call is this:

```
 private static void generateReport() {
    String karateOutputPath = "target/surefire-reports";
    Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
    List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
    for(File file: jsonFiles)
    {
        jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "demo");
    ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
    reportBuilder.generateReports();        
}
```

i dont know how library need to reportBuilder, listFiles, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in detail in the documentation, please read it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report

Comment: `FileUtils.listFiles` is not defined, Tried using both apache & karate FileUtils packages.

Comment: @GoodSp33d then please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Fixed ! Worked around by specifying the class with apache package. Lil bit rusted on Java, thanks for replying.